# mySQL DISTINCT and JOINS

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, distinct

***QUERY***

```
SELECT DISTINCT(o.id) as `order_line`,
  `k`.`short_name` AS `market`,
  `jc`.`code` AS `job_status`,
  `j`.`order_number` AS `job_number`,
  CONCAT('ML', `l`.`supp`) AS `supp_number`,
  `jd`.`needed_by` AS `needed_by`,
  `jd`.`mastec_onjob` AS `mastec_onjob`,
  `jd`.`revised_crcd` AS `revised_crcd`,
  `e`.`lastname` AS `install supervisor`,
  `o`.`order_number` AS `po number`,
  `o`.`order_date` AS `ordered`,
  `o`.`qty_ordered` AS `qty_ordered`,
  `o`.`ship_date` AS `vendor ship`,
  `o`.`rcvd_date` AS `rcvd_date`,
  `o`.`qty_received` AS `qty_received`,
  `m`.`mastec_partno` AS `mastec_partno`,
  `v`.`long_name` AS `vendor_name`,
  `o`.`mm_notes` AS `mm_notes`,
  `o`.`pm_notes` AS `pm_notes`,
  `o`.`rc_notes` AS `rc_notes` 
FROM
  mm_orders as o 
  LEFT JOIN `material_lists` `l` 
    ON ((`l`.`id` = `o`.`ml_id`)) 
  LEFT JOIN `jobs` `j` 
    ON ((`l`.`job_id` = `j`.`id`)) 
  LEFT JOIN `clli` `c` 
    ON ((`j`.`clli` = `c`.`id`)) 
  LEFT JOIN `markets` `k` 
    ON ((`k`.`id` = `c`.`market`)) 
  LEFT JOIN `employees` `e` 
    ON ((`e`.`employee_number` = `j`.`install_supervisor`)) 
  LEFT JOIN `job_dates` `jd` 
    ON ((`l`.`job_id` = `jd`.`job_id`)) 
  LEFT JOIN `mat_r12` `m` 
    ON ((`o`.`ci_id` = `m`.`id`)) 
  LEFT JOIN `vendors` `v` 
    ON ((`v`.`id` = `m`.`vendor_id`)) 
  LEFT JOIN `ml_contents` `mc` 
    ON ((`l`.`id` = `mc`.`ml_id`)) 
  LEFT JOIN `job_status_codes` `jc` 
    ON ((`j`.`status` = `jc`.`id`)) 
WHERE o.qty_ordered > o.qty_received 
  AND `j`.`status` IN (1, 5, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14)
  AND `mc`.`mastec_stock` = 0 
ORDER BY `j`.`order_number`,
  `l`.`id`,
  `l`.`supp`,
  `o`.`vendor_id`;
```

I want the results to reflect only one row per `o.id` but that's not at all what I'm getting. When I remove the `GROUP BY`, I get 63391 rows and with it there, I only get 188 rows. When I run `SELECT id FROM mm_orders WHERE qty_ordered > qty_received`, I get the proper number of rows at 1249.  Obviously, I am not the *MySQL* master that I thought I was. Is it my `JOIN`s or have I just completely botched the query from one end to the other?

In case the hierarchy is unclear, from top to bottom: job-> material_list-> `ml_contents`. Multiple `material_lists` can be assigned the same `job_id`, multiple `ml_contents` are within the same `material_list`.  The following tables have one-to-one relationships: job-> job_dates, ml_contents-> `mm_orders`.  All the others should be self-explanatory but if there is a good **jsFiddle** type of tool for **MySQL**, I'd be glad to post the structures of each table.

***QUERY UPDATED***

Answer (score 0):

It is the joins. You used inner joins, but maybe some orders don't have a material list or installer or whatever. Those orders will not be in the end result, causing it to drop down to 188 unique orders.

Furthermore, if the job for an order has multiple job dates, you will get that order in the result for every job date it has. That will cause the end result of 188 unique orders to be displayed as 63391 rows.

So, rather than applying grouping and distinct to try and solve it, you should first ask yourself what it is you want to query. Do you want to have a list of unique orders, or do you also want extra information? If the latter, be aware that the query contains for instance order lines, or job dates, and that the order information itself may be duplicated.

Comment: I'm still playing with the QUERY. I'm now using `SELECT DISTINCT(o.id)` at the beginning and converted all the `JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s. Now I get 201 rows. The correct number of rows (based on the direct query of the *mm_orders* table mentioned in my OP) is 1249. This is how many results I want in the result set and yes, I need all the additional data in there as well, because the result set is being stored as a `VIEW`.

Comment: But all those joins, as well as the conditions in the `WHERE` clause can affect the number of rows. You validate quantityOrdered agains quantityDelivered and you check the status of the job. So obviously this will affect the result.

Comment: Ah, you're right. The WHERE conditions are crucial criteria and I did not consider the number of rows that would be decreased from the 1249. However, I'm positive that 200 is too few and 63391 is too many.